# I'm stuck, how can I implement 2 different server methods in datasnap rest Delphi

Tags: delphi

Please, I need implement this

```
http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/clients/getinvoices

http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/suppliers/getorders
```

Where should I put the implementations for clients and suppliers?

Now I have the following code but my provider needs it to be implemented that way

My implementation :

```
http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/clients_getinvoices/1
http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/suppliers_getorders/100
```

Suppliers implementation

```
http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/clients/getinvoices/1
http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/suppliers/getorder/100**
```

The project RestServer consists of:

```
Initial form // where the server start stop
serverContainer
ServermethodsUnit1
WebModuleUnit1

Unit  ServerMethodsUni1

interface
uses system...... etc

type 

{$METHODINFO ON}
 TMyClass =class(TdataModule)
 FdConnection : TFDConeccion;
prvate
public
  function clients_getinvoices(id :string) : TjsonObject;
  function suppliers_getorders(id :string) : TjsonObject;
end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}
:
:
:
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do it. Looks like you have to put them on two different ServerMethods units, so you can have their URIClassName as another level of the call. Note: on the WebModule unit you will need to add a second DSServerClass to link the calls of the second ServerMethods. http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/DataSnap_REST#URI_Mapping

Comment: Thanks, Marc, but in the WebModule, there is no serverClass, however it exists in the serverContainer unit. Is There where i must put the DsServerclass??. If So, The Server property of the DsServerClass must be the same of the default, (Server) or i have to add a new DSserver??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as Marc suggested: add another `DSServerClass` component to the `ServerContainerunit` form.  Connect that to a second servermethodsunit. The wizard will allow you to create one using File->New->Other->DataSnap->ServerModule.

Both `DSServerClass` components on the ServerContainerunit share the 1 `DSServer` via their `Server` properties. And rename your servermethods' TDSServerMethods instances. 1 as `clients` and 2 as `suppliers`. `clients` will have the `getInvoices` method, and `suppliers` will have the `getorders` method.

```
unit ServerMethodsUnit2;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Datasnap.DSServer, 
  Datasnap.DSAuth, Datasnap.DSProviderDataModuleAdapter;

type
  TSuppliers = class(TDSServerModule)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function EchoString(Value: string): string;
    function ReverseString(Value: string): string;
  end;

implementation

uses
  System.StrUtils;

{%CLASSGROUP 'Vcl.Controls.TControl'}

{$R *.dfm}

{ Suppliers }

function TSuppliers.EchoString(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := Value + ' ' + Value;
end;

function TSuppliers.ReverseString(Value: string): string;
begin
  Result := System.StrUtils.ReverseString(Value);
end;

end.
```

And implement the `onGetClass` methods of the each of the 2 `DSServerClass` components, for example:

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSServerClass2GetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := ServerMethodsUnit2.TSuppliers;
end;
```

Comment: Hi nolaspeaker, 
i got an eror when change the name of the TDSServerMethods (via Refactoring)
The error is :  **"Error in module ServerMethodsUnit1: Declaration of class TserverMethods1 is missing or incorect"**

Comment: Then you didn't do it right. I have updated my answer to include a complete sample Servermthodsunit2 where the TDSServerModule is name 'Suppliers'. It compiles!

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong, i do just like this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8kVqg7ho5zg, but when i change the name from Suppliers (suggested) to **T**suppliers then no error appear

Comment: can you share an initial proyect sample to myfirstname dot mysurename gmail dot com ??

Comment: @SebastianGautier You are correct. Object Names must start with a 'T'

Comment: but the call to a server must be ** http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/suppliers/getorder/100 ** and not http://localhost:8080/datsnap/rest/**T**suppliers/getorder/100

Comment: You can't have that. It's just the way the Datasnap architecture works. What's so bad about the 'T'?

Comment: What you want to do, is create a "Datasnap Rest Application" and not a "Datasnap Rest Server". Then double-click on the webmodule unit to bring up the Actions list...

Comment: Ok i must call the provider to talk about this, 
Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214589/discussion-between-sebastian-gautier-and-nolaspeaker).

Answer (score 1):

I Found the Solution,

Create a Suppliers class after

```
Unit  ServerMethodsUni1

interface
uses system...... etc

type 

{$METHODINFO ON}
 TMyClass =class(TdataModule)
 FdConnection : TFDConeccion;
prvate
public
  function clients_getinvoices(id :string) : TjsonObject;
  function suppliers_getorders(id :string) : TjsonObject;
end;
{$METHODINFO OFF}

Suppliers =class(TMyClass)
end;
```

Then in the ServerContainerUnit

```
procedure TServerContainer2.DSServerClass1GetClass(
  DSServerClass: TDSServerClass; var PersistentClass: TPersistentClass);
begin
  PersistentClass := ServerMethodsUnit1.Suppliers;
end;
```

Comment: You can unmark my answer if you want, and I will delete it.